# How to use Hibernate inside a Controller method in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, servlets, controller

I created a new MVC Template Project with STS and I have added all the dependencies to support Hibernate.

This is my root-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2"> 
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/> 
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/> 
</jdbc:embedded-database>   

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="contactDao" class="com.server.dao.impl.ContactDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.server.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

STS automatically creates a sample controller called HomeController.java:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "home";
 }
```

I suppose that when the web app is started on a server the beans declared in root-context.xml are automatically instantiated by the framework.

My question is: how can I get a reference to the instance of the objects ContactDao?
That is: how can I execute operations on my database?

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject `ContactDao` in your controller using the annotation:

```
@Autowired 
public void setContactDao(ContactDao contactDao) {
    ...
}
```

Use the interface (I'm guessing it's ContactDao) so that you will be able to change the implementation (might be usefull for testing).

Now you can use your contact DAO methods using `contactDao` object.

For more information on autowiring refer to http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-autowire

Comment: you woul dneed to make sure your app conext is set up to be annaotion driven too

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem :)